# Check if a collection contains ALL values from another collection with Deferred Execution

Tags: c#, linq

Consider the following classes:

```
public class Recipe
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RecipeFacet> RecipeFacets { get; set; }
}

public class RecipeFacet
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Facet Facet { get; set; }
    public string RecipeId { get; set; }
}

public class Facet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I need to improve an existing query. I was thinking of using Linq's deferred execution. How would I write a Linq query that returns only `Recipes`, that contains ALL `Facets` I specify in a list of `Tuples`?

This is the original code that loops through `Recipes` and its `Facets`.  It works but it is slow if my intial `results` query has lots of `Recipes`.

```
IQueryable<Recipe> result; //assume we have data here

string query = "Cuisine:American+Recipe-Type:dinners";
IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> taxFacets = query
            .Split(' ')
            .Select(tf => tf.Split(':'))
            .Select(tf => new Tuple<string, string>(tf[0], tf[1]))
            .Distinct();

var recipeFacetCollection = result.Select(r => r.RecipeFacets).ToList();
var matchedRecipesIds = new List<string>();

var recIds = result.Select(r => r.Id).ToList();

// initially, include all recipes
matchedRecipesIds.AddRange(recIds);

// loop through each recipe's facet collection
foreach (var col in recipeFacetCollection)
{
    // loop through the tax facets from the query
    foreach (var tf in taxFacets)
    {
        var exists = col.Any(f => f.Facet.Name.Equals(tf.Item2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        // remove any recipe that is missing a facet
        if (!exists)
        {
            matchedRecipesIds.Remove(col.First().RecipeId);
        }
    }
}

result = result.Where(r => matchedRecipesIds.Contains(r.Id));
```

How can I have a nice Linq query with deferred execution?

**UPDATE::**

Turning my Tuple into a List allows me to do this. But this query doesn't return any of my records.

This is my criteria:

`Recipes`, that have a collection of `RecipeFacts`, that contains `Facets` that have Name = "American" AND Name = "dinners".

```
var listFacets = new List<string>()
{
    "American",
    "dinners"
};

 result = result
      .Where(r => r.RecipeFacets
      .All(f => !listFacets.Any(t => t.Equals(f.Facet.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this from @Rimp's help.

**WHERE** - filter
**ALL** - Require that All values from `listFacets`
**ANY** - is in ANY of the `Facets`.

```
result = result
     .Where(x => listFacets
     .All(lf => x.RecipeFacets
     .Any(f => f.Facet.Slug.Equals(lf, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query logic selects all recipes whose facets don't exist in listFacets.
@Hung's logic is closer but selects recipes that have *all* of their facets in listFacets

I think that you want to select all recipes that contain all listFacets.

Simplifying the example to use lists of strings:

```
        var listFacets = new[] { "a", "d" };
        var recipes = new[] { new[] { "a" },
                              new[] { "a", "d" },
                              new[] { "a", "d", "e" },
                              new[] { "x" }
        };

        // correct query, returns 2 results ad and ade
        var result = recipes.Where(r => listFacets.All(f => r.Any(rf => rf == f)));
        // original incorrect query, returns x
        var result2 = recipes.Where(r => r.All(f => !listFacets.Any(rf => rf == f)));
```

Comment: Since you simplified the objects the query isn't the same. But thanks for the suggestion. I do think @hung is very close.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure cause your code block is quite long but here is what I can come up with

```
result = result.Where(r => r.RecipeFacets.All(f => taxFacets.Any(t => t.Item1.Equals(f.Facet.Name))));
```

Let me know if it helps or not

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  But I am getting this error:  "Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Tuple'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Comment: Can you post your code? Which line of code are you getting error?

Comment: I am using your suggestion.  Doing a result.toList() threw that error.

Comment: Strange! Can you share your code? Especially the part that generates `Tuple`. I ran my code and it worked fine without this error.

Comment: The code that generates the tuple is in the post above.

Comment: I added an update that doesn't use the tuple. The query doesn't throw an error anymore but I'm not getting the results I want.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the exclamation from the clause in the check on the listFacets collection.

```
result = result.Where(r => r.RecipeFacets.All(f => listFacets.Any(t => t.Equals(f.Facet.Name, StringComparison
```